# How in bat-file copy copy files from one source to only unique folders every time I copy?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I work in Windows 7. I copy from flash-stick to computer multiple times. I need bat-file to check if a folder with a certain name exists and if exists create a folder the same name but increased index every time and copy files from flash to this unique folder. How to make checking and increasing in bat?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: that sounds like a flashcard for a camera. Consider naming the folders with the date instead with an increased index. Makes it much easier to find something special. I name mine for example  `20150405`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code will loop until the new folder name has a number on the end that is higher than all the other folders. It will then make the new folder and copy all your files from your old folder to it. You only have to change the folder names.

```
@echo off
:loop
if exist "newfolder%number%\" (
    set /a number=%number%+1
    goto :loop
) else (
    mkdir "newfolder%number%\"
)
copy "oldfolder\*.*" "newfolder%number%\"
```

I am not quite sure what you were trying to do, because you provided no code, however I hope this will work for your needs.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried your code and it works perfect.